# Retrofit request body as a data class not working

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In my project I using the retrofit for API request.

When I send the request through **@Field params it's working fine.**

But the same request, same code I make **data class instead of @Field params my request never reach the server**. It throws "user_name" missing error.

**Working code: (with @Field params)**

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST
    fun login(
        @Url url: String,
        @Field("user_name") username: String,
        @Field("password") password: String
    ): Call<LoginResponse>
```

**Not working code (with Data class)**

```
    @POST
    fun login(
        @Url url: String,
        @Body loginRequest: LoginRequest
    ): Call<LoginResponse>
```

**My Data Class:**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

 data class LoginRequest(@SerializedName("user_name") val userName: String,
                        @SerializedName("password") val password: String)
```

I may miss something, but unable to figure it out.